# Mostrar nickname de usuario y cuantos posts a realizado

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Estoy buscando la ***consulta para sacar de una base de datos el nickname de usuario y cuantos posts a escrito ese usuario***. Muchas gracias.

Este es mi diseño de la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado con:

```
select usuarios.nickname, count(posts.usuario_id) AS 'numero de post'
from usuarios, posts
group by usuarios.nickname, posts.usuario_id;
```

Pero me da esto me cuenta los pósts bien pero los nombres me los repite:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que has intentado?

Answer (score 3):

A mi me funcionó de esta manera:

```
select usuarios.nickname, count(*) num_posts
from usuarios
join posts on posts.usuario_id = usuarios.id
group by usuarios.nickname;
```

Comment: Por favor mira [answer]. Esta perfecto contestarte a vos mismo, pero explica porque esto funciono, y recuerda aceptar tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la siguiente query con *INNER JOIN*:

```
SELECT usuarios.nickname, COUNT(posts.id) AS num_posts 
    FROM usuarios INNER JOIN posts 
    WHERE usuarios.id LIKE posts.usuario_id
    GROUP BY (usuarios.nickname)
```

o puedes usar alias para las tablas (normalmente para consultas donde requieres más campos):

```
SELECT u.nickname, COUNT(p.id) AS num_posts 
    FROM usuarios u INNER JOIN posts p
    WHERE u.id LIKE p.usuario_id
    GROUP BY (u.nickname)
```

Comment: no no me funciona solo me muestra un nombre de usuario y 1 numero...

Comment: Te falta agrupar Orici

Comment: Siempre que uses una función de agregación, agrupa por el resto de columnas del SELECT

Comment: si he agrupado por nickname pero no funciona